# Dataframe of text data, remove symbols to clean the text

Tags: python, dataframe, text

I have a large dataframe with one column of a large index of emails.  Needless to say there are tons of symbols I'd like to get rid of so I can process the data.  I find the following code works:

`test=test.str.replace('&','')`

However, I'd like to also remove /123456789#[!^>]. But when I try and do this, the dataframe wipes out:

```
test=test.str.replace('#','/','')
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: So sorry @TrentonMcKinney , guess I didn't search hard enough for the answer.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular exression

```
import re
s = '145&&!*Hi!#$#%@*+_{ '
reg = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]')
print(reg.sub('', s))
```

ouput: Hi